# How do you call a "Proxy" that delegates to *several* implementations?

Tags: design-patterns

In a traditional GoF Proxy, you have an Interface, an Implementation, that implements the Interface, and a Proxy that also implements the Interface, references an instance of Implementation, and delegates the calls on the Interface methods to the same methods in the Implementation instance.

Say you would call the Interface/Implementation pair a "Fragment", and you would have several different such pairs. Now imagine you create a Whole Interface that implemented all those Fragment interfaces, and a single Whole Proxy that implemented the Whole Interface, and delegated to the appropriate Fragment Implementation instance.

A code (Java) example:

```
// Fragment A:
interface FragmentA { ... }
class FragmentAImpl implements FragmentA { ... }
// Whole A. That is the interface that "clients use"
interfaces WholeA extends FragmentA { // EMPTY! }
// *automatically generated* Proxy:
class ProxyA implements WholeA {
    private FragmentA implA;
    // Implements FragmentA through delegation to implA
}

// Fragment B:
interface FragmentB { ... }
class FragmentBImpl implements FragmentB { ... }
// Whole B. That is the interface that "clients use"
interfaces WholeB extends WholeA, FragmentB { // EMPTY! }
// *automatically generated* Proxy:
class ProxyB extends ProxyA implements WholeB {
    private FragmentB implB;
    // Implements FragmentB through delegation to implB
}

// Fragment C: similar to Fragment B, but with different *added behavior*.
```

Is this pattern at all (since Patterns must be common solution to common problems)? And if so, as it got a name? Or could it be cleanly defined as a combination of patterns?

Being able to clearly describe how this code works in terms of patterns would make it much easier to explain to others how create compatible code, and help to find a framework that already implements this pattern.

A *Proxy* normally delegates to *a single instance*.

A *Facade* normally offers *a different interface* to that *multiple objects* it hides.

A *Bridge* also offers *a different interface* to that the *single instance* it hides.

A *Composite* expects all components to *share the same base interface*.

A *Decorator* extends the interface of the wrapped object, like here, but normally *implements the additional functionality itself*, instead of delegating to another objects.

A Whole that implements a single Fragment is just a Proxy pattern, but a Whole that extends another Whole is closest to a Decorator pattern.

There are several reasons to do it this way. Firstly, client code should see WholeB as extending WholeA, although the implementer of FragmentB cannot extend FragmentA (which was implemented by someone else). Secondly, references to WholeX (ProxyX) stay valid, even if implementation of FragmentX is replaced a runtime. Thirdly, both ProxyB and ProxyC can share *the same instance* of FragmentAImpl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I'd still go with facade.**

It offers a single port of call for clients needing the services of several interfaces. This is a facade. The fact that normally a facade declares a specific interface instead of re-using the ones from the classes/objects it aggregates is, to me, an implementation detail.

*Update*

From the GoF book:

> *Intent*: Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a
>   subsystem. Facade defines a higher-level interface that makes the
>   subsystems easier to use.

Especially when you then read

> *Motivation*: Structuring a system into sybsystems helps reduce
>   complexity. A common design goal it to minimize the communication and
>   dependencies between subsysems. One way to achieve this goal is to
>   introduce a **facade** object that provides a single, simplified
>   interface to the more general facilities of a subsystem.

While the comment by @pdr would seem correct, I would argue differently.

The "simplified" interface can most certainly be the same as the interfaces put behind the facade. Its just a question of how simple those "facaded" interfaces are.

Plus, I don't take "simplifies" as a requirement for an object to be a facade.

The motivation to minimize communication and dependencies between subsystems is far more important and the main goal of the facade pattern. A facade **object** providing a single point of access to multiple (unchanged interfaces of) subsystems, still fulfills this goal regardless of whether it (also) simplifies the interface(s) offered by the subsystems it hides.

Comment: Short, concise, correct and not confusing. The better answer to this question.

Comment: This is incorrect. A Facade is a simplification of an interface; it can't be the same.

Comment: @pdr I do not agree, see update to answer.

Comment: I'm still not seeing how any part of that motivation is achieved here. In fact, now that I read the final paragraph again, particularly the last sentence, I am convinced that the OPs motivation matches more closely the Proxy pattern. But I still maintain we don't have enough information to give it a name.

Comment: @pdr I can see why you see it as a Proxy. However, the motivation for a Proxy is for example to delay resource or otherwise expensive initialization/instantiation of the object behind the proxy until it is actually needed. The motivation of the poster seems to be to hide away multiple instances behind a single ..., well, facade (sorry couldn't resist), so that object serves as a decoupling point between what is in front and behind of it. If you have a copy of the GoF book, the picture in the Facade discussion makes that much clearer than I seem able to convey.

Comment: @pdr: In OOP, nearly everything is an interface, I hope you understand what I mean. A facade is a kind of proxy, it can span multiple objects and provide a single interface for them. If the interaction between those objects needs to be orchestrated, then you have a mediator.

Comment: @Marjam Venema: I disagree with that definition of proxy. When I read your sentence it almost seems like the proxy is a creational pattern. But it's just a plain object providing access to another plain object. It can be used for various purposes, not only for resource initialization. It's often times used for interception, useful for example for implementing cross cutting concerns in AOP. There needn't be heavy objects or resources involved at all.

Comment: @Falcon: I never said it was a creational pattern. It isn't. Proxy can indeed be used for many things. The example I gave is just one example and is paraphrased from the motivation in the GoF book...

Comment: @Marjan Venema: I know, but the explanation above sounds a bit like that in my ears. There're many use cases of proxies which don't involve resources or initializations at all, for example controlling access privileges.

Comment: @Marjan: The more I think about this question, the more I think the OP is probably trying to use a Facade but is doing so incorrectly. I can't imagine why he's building multiple classes, each with their own interface, rather than having multiple simpler interfaces to a single complex class. Now that would be a Facade.

Comment: @pdr: No, that wouldn't be a facade, but a class with too many responsibilities. He is building multiple classes so each can adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle. He is creating the Facade (which should only be a pass-through class and thus wouldn't be too much of a SRP violation) to decouple all of them from the rest of his app.

Comment: @Marjan: Now you're either assuming too much or just being contrary. SRP can be preserved within a class with a complex API with good use of encapsulation. Whereas, the way the OP has made every ProxyX class extend ProxyA, instead of encapsulating FragmentA smells of an LSP violation. Although, again, I don't think we have enough information to ascertain that for sure.

Comment: @pdr I am never contrary for just being contrary... I don't see how encapsulation helps preserve SRP. You would still be giving a single class way too much to do, even if you use composition and/or aggregation of other classes into that single class. Providing a facade (and having just pass-through code in there) is about the only good enough reason for me to do so. With regard to LSP and the poster's example: I always read LSP to pertain to class inheritance and not to interfaces, but you may be right, I am not well enough into Java to spot code smells as easily as I do in Delphi...

Answer (score 7):

A mediator? Or inverse multiplexer?

Anyhow, there's no reason to dogmatically stick to the exact same patterns in GoF.
That book should expand your professional vocabulary and maybe even teach you some good ideas, but it's not the programmer's ten commandments.

I couldn't see a reason for you here to actually use the Proxy pattern, theoretically.

Having a separated interface/implementation is very good, but that doesn't mean it has to act as a proxy. If you want a name for it, just label it as "loosely coupled".

You can call it any name that makes sense. You don't have to try to dig up a standard name when it's not totally obvious.

In general, I find that the whole dogmatic way of creating clean code is sometimes deviant from the original purpose - to create code that's easy to read and understand.

If you can't find a completely standard name for what you're doing, don't try to turn it into an existing pattern or name. That only confuses fellow programmers.

Just give it a new one that makes sense to you and your fellow programmers. Consult, together, in *your* workplace - where it matters.

Comment: I don't think Mediator is correct either, because it's goal is to "prevent" the different objects implementing the behavior to "know each other". But in my proposed design, I don't want to prevent FragmentB of knowing FragmentA, I just want to enable FragmentB to exist without knowing *the concrete implementation* of FragmentA.

Comment: And while I agree with your answer (+1), I'll go with Marjan. A Facade doesn't stop being a Facade because it expose the same interface as the objects it delegates to.

Comment: You're abusing design patterns here. Like I said, you're looking for loose-coupling, not proxies. Proxies are generally used to present a lighter interface to large complex objects, or to access remote objects, etc. I think it's a bad idea to use a pattern here. Like I said, you only want loose-coupling, and that's a very basic term.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to separate design patterns by their implementation details. Doing so will cause great confusion when you come to Strategy and State, or cause you to overcomplicate things to avoid having arguments on the Execute method of a Command.

Separate design patterns by their intent. To take your five examples:

A Proxy is a class which creates an interface to something expensive, which is not eaily duplicated, like a network connection or a large chunk of memory. * see comments

A Facade is a simplification of an overcomplicated API. Reducing the surface area, as they say; making it simpler to use.

A Bridge is where an abstraction is decoupled from the implementation, so that when the implementation changes, the calling code doesn't have to. Initially, the interface doesn't have to be different, as you suggested, you just can't insist on them remaining the same.

A Composite is for taking multiple objects and wrapping them in a single abstraction.

A Decorator allows objects to get wrapped in objects with the same interface, so that they add functionality without changing the calling code.

It's hard to tell from your example which you are trying to implement, because you've described the implementation and not the intent. But I'm guessing that the Proxy pattern is appropriate.

Comment: In my understanding a proxy needn't necessarily wrap something expensive. A proxy is just an interface to control access to another object. Often times this pattern is used to provide lazy loading behaviour or for interception purposes. A facade is pretty similar, it is usually used to provide a simpler interface, but it can also be used to provide an interface to multiple classes.

Comment: I should add: The proxy shares the interface of the *single* class it wraps.

Comment: @Falcon: The point of the Proxy is to have a heavyweight object which can be instantiated by a lightweight object when needed and kept around if its likely to be needed again. This way, the heavyweight object only needs to know how it operates and the client only needs to know that it wants the object, the Proxy's sole responsibility is really to decide when to do what for efficiency.

Comment: I really don't agree. The point of the proxy is to control access to another object and nothing else. If the object is heavyweight or not is totally irrelevant. What about AOP proxies for example? They're often used to provide simple logging mechanisms or to control access privileges? They statisfy the requirements for a proxy and do not involve heavy objects.

Comment: @Falcon: Googling around, I can see your point. I'm still not entirely convinced this was the original intent and this would explain why four different names have grown for different types of Proxy. The one I'm referring to being the Virtual Proxy. But ok, I stand corrected.

Comment: I found that, too, and I also have some deeper insight in the various kinds of proxies, thanks to this discussion.